# Viewing records created by user's

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

Is it possible to use  Apex and soql/sosl so as to get a list of all records across all objects created by a user? I tried dynamic soql , but ran into governor limits. Does anyone have any better idea?

Comment: what's you complete use case ? are you trying this for any business requirement ? and how do you want to present the information back ? in a web page or export to excel ?